# Accessing Google Docs from GMail Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, gmail-addons

I am having problems accessing Google Docs from a GMail Add-On.

I want to copy particular Google Docs file from my GMail Add-On, and then edit the new doc.  I am able to create a new doc from my template doc, using:

```
  var docTemplate="<DOCUMENT ID>";
  var docName = "Generated Document 123";
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName).getId();
```

However, when I try to open the file using this code:

```
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
```

I get an error in the GMail Add-On pane saying *"You do not have permission to call openById [line: 36, function: getContextualAddOn, file: Code]"*

I've used this same code successfully in a Apps Script in Google Sheets, so I assume I haven't set up my permissions correctly.

In my manifest file, I set the oauthScopes values as:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ]
```

The /auth/drive permission allows me to call DriveApp.getFileById(), but what different permission do I need to call DocumentApp.openById()?  Or is there some other issue?

Any pointers / guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your scopes: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"`

Comment: Adding "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents" to my oauthScopes solved it.  Thanks!  (My upvote was recorded but not displayed.)

Comment: Yes, that gets you past the permissions part of it.  I encountered another error after that which may speak to the point of the comment below.  How did you do?

Comment: I am able to access my documents (Google Docs) just fine.  E.g., 

`var doc = DocumentApp.create(myFileName);`

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in [Using Apps Script services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask
>   users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can
>   only call services that do not have access to personal data,
>   specifically the following:
>
> **> Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or
>   SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl())**